# Verb for conversing via text messages

Tags: single-word-requests

I was thinking to myself of how to succinctly speak about a conversation I had over a text message and found myself struggling to find a word for it.  I'm looking for **a single verb which means to converse with someone specifically via a text message format**.  All the words I could think of (such as 'converse' and 'talked') have connotations of a verbal communication which of course does not occur in the context of text messaging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The verb is simply *text.*

Definition:

> To communicate by text messaging.

Example:

> I *texted* her a little while ago.

[(Merriam-Webster)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/text)

Comment: Silly me; of course!  And so naturally the verb I was looking for was 'I was **texting** with X...'

Comment: And an episode of texting I would describe as a *text conversation*. I also use the terms *email conversation*, or *email correspondence*. Which one I use depends on the length of time over which the conversation/correspondence takes place.